# 3 column responsive layout becomes 2 column layout with center column moving to bottom in mobile resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I need to know if it is possible to have a center fixed sized column to appear below the left(fixed pixel width) and right(fluid) columns when the page is shrunk to mobile view, thus becoming fluid to the full width of the parent container div.

Bootstrap library is available, but the left column in this case is fixed to an exact pixel width.

example here: [image]

Comment: The formatting is very specific. You will have to define media queries for the fixed widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGzpKz

Using the calc CSS3 function inside the width property helps you do things you normally would have to use javascript for.

In the link I sent you, I simply put all my columns inside a wrapper.
All these columns are floated left, except the orange one, which is floating right. Making this allow any left floating item to fill the remaining space between the blue and the orange columns.

I then set my orange div width to be:

```
width: calc(100% - (200px * 2))
```

200px being the width of one fixed-width column.

Then, on mobile, I just tell the red column to go back where it belongs by setting its width to 100% and I tell the orange one that it has only one column left on its side.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .wrapper{
    .column{
      float: left;
      &:nth-child(2){
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
      }
      &:last-child{
        width: calc(100%);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just implemented this solution and it is working exactly as demonstrated.  You provided everything I needed to easily implement it into my existing css structure as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the columns in bootstrap, you can use push and pull classes

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     A
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-6">
     B
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-3">
     C
</div>
```

### [Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/99lob5BTZT)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried this, but the issue is that the left and middle column have to be a fixed width in the larger tablet/desktop resolutions.  I was unable to do this using purely bootstrap classes.